# string comparison in bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm studying bash scripts.
I got the sample script below from the web.

```
#!/bin/bash

str="test"

if [ x$str == x"test" ]; then
  echo "hello!"
fi
```

What is x on fifth line(`x$str` and `x"test"`)?
Does "`x`" have special meaning?

Answer (score 10):

No special meaning, but if `$str` was empty, then the

```
if [ $str == "test" ]
```

would result in a substitution of nothing into the test and it would be like this

```
if [  == "test" ]
```

which would be a syntax error.  Adding the X in front would resolve this, however quoting it like this

```
if [ "$str" == "test" ]
```

is a more readable and understandable way of achieving the same.

Comment: Looks like the example was taken from the testcases used to test a fresh bash compile, only reference I've found to the prepend x method was arguing that the "" method was better and whether the test case should be changed.

Comment: What is better is a matter of taste -- I have seen the x method a few places, and im sure there are places in pipelines or deep substitutions where it would actually make the code more readable -- however for simple cases like the one above, the "" is intuitively understood and would never have raised a question.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't say it was my argument, I said it was the argument on the GNU bash mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

It's to make sure that the left side of the expression in your example is not empty. If `str` was not set, the condition would otherwise be `[  == "test" ]` which would give an error.

Instead of using an single letter to make it not-empty, you could also put the variable inside double quotation characters, and skip the `x` completely (`[ "$str" == "test" ]`).